# Drawing rectangle with geo coordinates (north/south, east/west) using QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I need a layer with a rectangle that maps it's top left and bottom right corners to north/south and east/west coordinates. This is an Area of Interest which I need to overlay another image layer to see if the things I'm looking for are in the AOI.

How do I do this in QGIS?

It seems hard to find a decent tutorial.

Comment: Your question is tagged with `qgis-plugins` - are you writing a plugin?

Comment: No. The tag description is "Software plugins that add functionality to the QGIS package" (vs Development of Software plugins that add functionality to the QGIS package) and so I tagged the question in case there was a plugin that was relevant.

Comment: That's what I thought, and I based my answers on that assumption. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 9):

Because QGIS has more than one way to accomplish a goal, here's another answer.

First, create a new layer in the CRS of your point coordinates. (If the point coordinates are in latitude and longitude, the CRS is EPSG:4326.) It doesn't matter what its geometry type is. Add four fields to the attribute table: xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax. Choose decimal number as the field type. Add a new feature, enter the xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax values from your corner points. Your top-left point is (xmin,ymax). Your bottom-right corner point is (xmax,ymin).

Use the `Geometry by Expression` tool (from the processing toolbox)

- Choose Input Layer: any layer that has the same CRS as the point coordinates.
- Choose Output geometry type: Polygon
- Use this for the Geometry expression:

  ```
    make_polygon( make_line( make_point( xmin,ymin), make_point( xmin,ymax), make_point( xmax,ymax), make_point( xmax,ymin), make_point( xmin,ymin)))
  ```

Obviously this method is more complicated than my other suggestion. It doesn't make sense to do it this way for only one rectangle. But if you have a lot of rectangles to create, this method will be more efficient than running `create grid` multiple times. Simply add as many features to the layer as you want to create rectangles.

Comment: this (mostly) works for me...layer is created, attribute table is populated, but the polygons don't draw.  What am I missing?

Comment: Impossible to tell without more details. I suggest you post a question, and include screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a manual way of doing it. It is not the fastest but it is straightforward.

Create a new polygon with 4 points (it could be roughly over the area of interest or not, it's not important at this stage).

Enable the `vertex editing tool` for this layer, right click on the 1st vertex of the layer

[image]

Edit the coordinates of the four points to get your desired polygon (the last one is automatically updated to the same value as the 1st one)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the tool `Create Grid` from the Processing Toolbox.

- Choose Grid Type: Rectangle (Polygon)
- Set the Grid Extent using the corner coordinates.
- Make the Horizontal Spacing the same as the width of your rectangle (calculate as xmax -xmin).
- Make the Vertical Spacing the same as the height of your rectangle (calculate as ymax - ymin)

For example, these settings make a rectangle 5 degrees wide and 2 degrees long, with its top left corner at lat/long (0,2) and its bottom right corner at lat/long (5,0).

[image]